# Java Checking multiple ifs

Tags: java

I'm creating a roulette wheel game where a group of numbers equals red and the other group equals black. 
The game will output a random number 1-36 and the numbers correspond the red or black. How would I do something like the code below?

```
if (rouletteSpin == (2|4|6|8|10|11|13|15|17|20|22|24|26|28|29|31|33|35))
```

so that it is checking multiple scenarios

Comment: You could say `if (rouletteSpin == 2 || rouletteSpin == 4 || rouletteSpin == 6 || ... _ad nauseam_)`.  But a better way would be to learn about the `Set` type.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html.

Comment: By the way, if `rouletteSpin` is an `int`, how are you going to distinguish "0" from "00"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to do a lot of boolean OR statements.

Alternatively, you could add all numbers to a Set object then simply do `if set.contains(rouletteSpin)`

Which, if you're interested in performance, is faster than using a list or array. (constant vs linear)

You can declare such a Set like

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>;
set.add(num); // for all your numbers
```

It also makes sense to store only one set of numbers since there are two colors (red and black). If the red set doesn't contain the number, it must be black.

Answer (score 2):

Make sth like:

```
private static final Set<Integer> RED = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        new HashSet<Integer>(
        Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35)));
```

and then use

```
RED.contains(rouletteSpin);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your values into a list, like

```
List<Integer> color = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6); // And so on
```

Then use contains in the if-clause:

```
if(color.contains(rouletteSpin) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Wow so many answers. I'll try some of these and come back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using arrays or sets or other collection to combine all the items, e.g.

```
  private static int[] reds = new int[] {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...};
```

and then check

```
  if (Arrays.stream(reds).anyMatch(i -> i == rouletteSpin)) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a list of red and query the list. example:

```
Integer[] redArray = {1, 3, 5 ...};
List<Integer> red = Arrays.asList(redArray);
int num = 3;
if(red.contains(num)){
    System.out.println("red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the `HashSet` approach has its merits, here is an alternative not yet mentioned:

```
switch(x) {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
  doSomething();
  break;
case 2:
case 4:
case 6:
case 8:
  doSomethingElse();
  break;
default:
  fail();
  break;
}
```

This also works with enums, i.e. `ROLL_00, ROLL_0, ROLL_1`, ... and the compiler can even assist in checking that you did not miss any of the options then!